# Method is called many times, but should be called once. Don't see why?

Tags: vue.js, meteor, mongoose

I'm trying to test but I'm having a problem I can't find a solution to, this is my test.. it's not very good I know but I need solution.

This is my method:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method'
import { CallPromiseMixin } from 'meteor/didericis:callpromise-mixin'

import Journal from '../journals/journals'
import JournalDetails from '../journals/journal-details'

export const journalMigrateTotDecimal = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'app.journalMigrateTotDecimal',
  mixins: [CallPromiseMixin],
  validate: null,
  async run() {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      let res
      console.log('start....');
      let journals = await Journal.find().lean()
      res = await Journal.deleteMany({})
      res = await Journal.insertMany(journals)
      console.log('done journal!');
      let journalDetails = await JournalDetails.find().lean()
      res = await JournalDetails.deleteMany({})
      res = await JournalDetails.insertMany(journalDetails)
      console.log('done journal details!');
    return res
   }
  },
})
```

Call on client:

```html
<ElButton type="primary" @click="migrateJournalData">
      Journal
</ElButton>
```

```js
methods: {
 migrateJournalData() {
  this.loading = true
  journalMigrateTotDecimal
    .callPromise()
    .then(res => {
      this.loading = false
      console.log('res', res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.loading = false
      console.log('err', err)
    })
  },
},
```

The problem is the method is called more than once and I don't know why. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you ensure that the call is not invoked multiple times from the client?

Comment: yes  I just click once time on button

Comment: This is not a safe way to ensure the method being called only once from the client. You can for example place a `debugger` statement inside `migrateJournalData` to track it's invocation.

Comment: it show like that  ` start .... done journal! start... done journal detail! start... done journal ! done journal detail start.... done journal! done journal detail!` any show more not stopping.

Comment: My data collection maybe 800000 records.